# loop if which command until the first match and store it in a variable

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop, if-statement, match

I am trying to find the highest version of the C & C++ compiler installed on the OS.

I'm trying to optimize my code instead of taking up 25 lines and rewriting a bunch of `if which` commands over and over.

The script can be accessed by anyone on any version of distros and so the list can be long and full of possibilities and I want the latest version to run the build.

The reason I am posting this is because I keep getting back the match `gcc-11` when `gcc-12` is installed and shows up when manually running `which gcc-12`... so why is it only matching a lower version?

```
#!/bin/bash

clear

c_compilers=(gcc-13 gcc-12 gcc-11 gcc-10 gcc-9 gcc clang-16 clang-15 clang-14 clang-13 clang-12 clang-11 clang-10 clang)
cxx_compilers=(g++-13 g++-12 g++-11 g++-10 g++-9 g++ clang++-16 clang++-15 clang++-14 clang++-13 clang++-12 clang++-11 clang++-10 clang++)

for i in ${c_compilers[@]}
do
    cc_match="$(which $i)"
    if [ -n "$cc_match" ]; then
        CC="$cc_match"
        break
    fi
done

for i in ${cxx_compilers[@]}
do
    cxx_match="$(which $i)"
    if [ -n "$cxx_match" ]; then
        CXX="$cxx_match"
        break
    fi
done

echo $PATH
echo $CC
echo $CXX
```

Comment: Try putting `set -x` before this to get an execution trace as it runs, so you can see exactly where it's going wrong. Also, I don't think it's related, but there are a number of places where you really should double-quote variable references; [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) will point them out.

Comment: there are builtin commands that are better than `which` -- https://stackoverflow.com/q/592620/7552

Comment: `for c in "${c_compilers[@]}"; do command -v "$c" &> /dev/null && { CC="$c"; break; }; done`?

Answer (score 0):

Since no one else had an answer I used the advice from the comments to come up with this.

```
#!/bin/bash
clear

# find the highest gcc version you have installed and set it as your CC compiler
type -P 'gcc' && export CC='gcc'
type -P 'gcc-9' && export CC='gcc-9'
type -P 'gcc-10' && export CC='gcc-10'
type -P 'gcc-11' && export CC='gcc-11'
type -P 'gcc-12' && export CC='gcc-12'
type -P 'gcc-13' && export CC='gcc-13'

# find the highest g++ version you have installed and set it as your CXX compiler
type -P 'g++' && export CXX='g++'
type -P 'g++-9' && export CXX='g++-9'
type -P 'g++-10' && export CXX='g++-10'
type -P 'g++-11' && export CXX='g++-11'
type -P 'g++-12' && export CXX='g++-12'
type -P 'g++-13' && export CXX='g++-13'

echo
echo $CC
echo
echo $CXX
```